# ASP.NET Output caching Location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I need to know where the files are saved when a page is cached using the following:

`<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="None" %>`

Because sometimes I need to delete the files to 'reset' the page so I can get the latest data.

EDIT: A second question: does the above line uses the memory of the server to save the cached pages?

Thanks

Comment: rather than deleting the files from the location, u can clear the cache of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [RemoveOutputCacheItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/914c7ktw.aspx) method to remove a cached page.

> does the above line uses the memory of the server to save the cached pages?

This will depend on the value of the [Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation.aspx) attribute. If you set it to `Server` then it will be stored in memory. If you set it to `Client`, then the page will be cached on the client browser.

Comment: A question, does my method uses the memory of the server? Because other caching methods saves external files to disk. So I think other methods are less stressful to the memory than this one?

Comment: @Ozkan, if you set location to server then it is stored in memory of the server. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I can only choose to save caching on Server, Client or a proxy between server and client. But I think, the best option is to save cache files on disk on server if you want full control of a page (Because if you choose to save on clients pc, you can't choose to delete cache files that are stored on a clients pc). I am right?

Comment: If the cache is saved in memory, is there a way to clean the cache besides restarting the server? Does killing w3wp.exe help?